# How to group dates in Quarters in SQLite

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, datetime, sql-date-functions

I need to group my dates as Quarters, April to June as Q1, Jul to Sep as Q2, Oct to Dec as Q3 and Jan to March as Q4

[image]

I need to add another column besides close_dates showing Quarters. I cannot find any date function i can use.
Any ideas on this.

Comment: See if this helps you: https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: this does not show how to divide the dates in quarters :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of your dates is **not** `YYYY-MM-DD` which is the only valid date format for SQLite.
So if you want to extract the month of a date, any date function that SQLite supports will fail.
You must use the string function [`SUBSTR()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) to extract the month and then other functions like [`NULLIF()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#nullif) and [`COALESCE()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce) to adjust the quarter to your requirement.
Assuming that the format of your dates is `DD/MM/YYYY`:

```
SELECT Close_Date,
       'Q' || COALESCE(NULLIF((SUBSTR(Close_Date, 4, 2) - 1) / 3, 0), 4) AS Quarter
FROM tablename
```

If the format is `MM/DD/YYYY` then change `SUBSTR(Close_Date, 4, 2)` to `SUBSTR(Close_Date, 1, 2)` or just `Close_Date` because SQLite will implicitly convert the date to a number which will be the starting digits of the date.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=01f1f97615185981c18596689c523ce2).
Results:

```
> Close_Date | Quarter
> :--------- | :------
> 01/04/2019 | Q1     
> 01/05/2019 | Q1     
> 01/10/2019 | Q3     
> 01/09/2019 | Q2     
> 01/06/2019 | Q1     
> 01/09/2019 | Q2     
> 01/04/2019 | Q1     
> 01/07/2019 | Q2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the month part and use a case expression:

```
select
    close_date,
    case 
        when 0 + strftime('%m', close_date) between  1 and  3 then 'Q4'
        when 0 + strftime('%m', close_date) between  4 and  6 then 'Q1'
        when 0 + strftime('%m', close_date) between  7 and  9 then 'Q2'
        when 0 + strftime('%m', close_date) between 10 and 12 then 'Q3'
    end as quarter
from mytable
```

The addition of `0` is there to force the conversion of the result of `strftime()` to a number.

This could also be expressed using date artihmetics (which lets you generate the fiscal year too):

```
select 
    close_date,
    strftime('%Y', close_date, '-3 months') 
        || 'Q' || ((strftime('%m', close_date, '-3 months') - 1) / 4) as year_quarter
from mytable
```

Comment: I ran the 1st query and the get None as the result under col quarter

Comment: @user14140366: this appears to work in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4e428109e063b5a6a5b512c1ed034f49)... In which format are you storing the dates? I must be `YYYY-MM-DD` for sqlite to recognize them as dates.

Comment: when I run dtypes in jupyter, i get object type as type

Comment: Yes COALESCE(NULLIF((strftime('%m', some_date) + 2) / 3, 0), 4) AS Quarter works for me

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with arithmetic rather than a `case` expression:

```
select floor( (strftime('%m', close_date) + 2) / 3 ) as quarter
```